# Hide Filters with no result of combination | Isotope JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-isotope

I am creating an application using [Isotope.js](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/) with checkbox combination filter. I am managing to get everything working using examples etc..

However I finding an issue how to hide certain filters which will give no results on the filter.

I have created a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lsg4zxu7/9/) to demonstrate my example.

Filter options:

```
<div id="options">
  <div class="option-set" data-group="brand">
    <input type="checkbox" value=""        id="brand-all" class="all" checked /><label for="brand-all">all brands</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value=".brand1" id="brand1" /><label for="brand1">brand1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value=".brand2" id="brand2" /><label for="brand2">brand2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="option-set" data-group="type">
    <input type="checkbox" value=""        id="type-all" class="all" checked /><label for="type-all">all types</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value=".type1" id="type1" /><label for="type1">type1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" value=".type2" id="type2" /><label for="type2">type2</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Items:

```
<div id="container">
  <div class="item brand1 type1 red"></div>
  <div class="item brand1 type1 red"></div>  
  <div class="item brand1 type1 red"></div>  
  <div class="item brand2 type2 blue"></div>  
  <div class="item brand2 type2 blue"></div>  
  <div class="item brand2 type2 blue"></div>  
</div>
```

In my example I have two filters brands & types. If brand 1 is selected as a filter only type 1 of that brand is available so I would like to hide the type 2 checkbox and works vice versa if all is selected.

It should work in a scalable way for any category and not hardcoded categories.

I have tried already achieving this by triggering isotope itself on the filters but didn't work. Also creating events on arrange complete, but still not managing to get the available categories from the filtered items.

Method on arrange items I tried using:

```
$$container.on( 'arrangeComplete', function( event, filteredItems ) {
  filteredItems.forEach(function(elementsData){
console.log($(elementsData.element).attr('class));
});
});
```

Can someone guide me to the correct solution as I've been hours trying different activations.

Comment: I clicked around a bit, one thing I don't understand is that I can get into a state where both brand1 is clicked and brand-all. That's probably not supposed to happen, right?

Comment: @NielsBom - No sir, all will untick all options and the moment you select one filter the all is unticked.

Comment: Currently, it doesn't work like that :-)

Comment: @NielsBom - Weird on my local dev its working like that, on JSFiddle isnt.

Comment: @NielsBom - If you ignore that fact, would it be possible to get this working ?

Comment: I tried for a bit, but outta time now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    /*jshint browser:true, undef: true, unused: true, jquery: true */

var $container;
var filters = {};

$(function(){

  $container = $('#container');

  var $filterDisplay = $('#filter-display');

  $container.isotope();
  // do stuff when checkbox change
  $('#options').on( 'change', function( jQEvent ) {
    var $checkbox = $( jQEvent.target );
    manageCheckbox( $checkbox );

    var comboFilter = getComboFilter( filters );

    $container.isotope({ filter: comboFilter });

    $filterDisplay.text( comboFilter );
    var comboFilters = comboFilter.split(', ');
    $(comboFilters).each(function(edx, val) {
    var myval = val;
    var hidelist = [];
    var showlist = [];
    $('.option-set input').each(function(edx, ele) {
      var selector = $(ele).attr("value") + myval;


      if(selector !== "" && $(selector).length === 0)
      {
        hidelist.push(ele);
        //$(ele).hide();
        //$("label[for='"+$(ele).attr('id')+"']").hide();
      }
      else {
      showlist.push(ele);
      }

    });
    $(hidelist).each(function(edx, item) {
            $(item).hide();
        $("label[for='"+$(item).attr('id')+"']").hide();
    });
    $(showlist).each(function(edx, item) {
            $(item).show();
        $("label[for='"+$(item).attr('id')+"']").show();
    });
  });

  });

});



function getComboFilter( filters ) {
  var i = 0;
  var comboFilters = [];
  var message = [];

  for ( var prop in filters ) {
    message.push( filters[ prop ].join(' ') );
    var filterGroup = filters[ prop ];
    // skip to next filter group if it doesn't have any values
    if ( !filterGroup.length ) {
      continue;
    }
    if ( i === 0 ) {
      // copy to new array
      comboFilters = filterGroup.slice(0);
    } else {
      var filterSelectors = [];
      // copy to fresh array
      var groupCombo = comboFilters.slice(0); // [ A, B ]
      // merge filter Groups
      for (var k=0, len3 = filterGroup.length; k < len3; k++) {
        for (var j=0, len2 = groupCombo.length; j < len2; j++) {
          filterSelectors.push( groupCombo[j] + filterGroup[k] ); // [ 1, 2 ]
        }

      }
      // apply filter selectors to combo filters for next group
      comboFilters = filterSelectors;
    }
    i++;
  }


  var comboFilter = comboFilters.join(', ');

  return comboFilter;
}

function manageCheckbox( $checkbox ) {
  var checkbox = $checkbox[0];

  var group = $checkbox.parents('.option-set').attr('data-group');
  // create array for filter group, if not there yet
  var filterGroup = filters[ group ];
  if ( !filterGroup ) {
    filterGroup = filters[ group ] = [];
  }

  var isAll = $checkbox.hasClass('all');
  // reset filter group if the all box was checked
  if ( isAll ) {
    delete filters[ group ];
    if ( !checkbox.checked ) {
      checkbox.checked = 'checked';
    }
  }
  // index of
  var index = $.inArray( checkbox.value, filterGroup );

  if ( checkbox.checked ) {
    var selector = isAll ? 'input' : 'input.all';
    $checkbox.siblings( selector ).removeAttr('checked');


    if ( !isAll && index === -1 ) {
      // add filter to group
      filters[ group ].push( checkbox.value );
    }

  } else if ( !isAll ) {
    // remove filter from group
    filters[ group ].splice( index, 1 );
    // if unchecked the last box, check the all
    if ( !$checkbox.siblings('[checked]').length ) {
      $checkbox.siblings('input.all').attr('checked', 'checked');
    }
  }

}
```

Fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/Lsg4zxu7/45/

Comment: I never see type2 anymore in your example.

Comment: This is not working on my end. Did you manage to make it work ?

Comment: I changes the type2 to type3 for testing, change it back and it will work as expected

Comment: @Yasir - Can you please provide me with an updated jsfiddle link ?

Comment: @Yasir - I changed it back to type 2 and it is not working as expected unfortunately

Comment: @Jojo: Sorry about that got the issue and fixed it to work for dynamic updates - https://jsfiddle.net/Lsg4zxu7/45/

Comment: @Yasir - On JSFiddle it seems to be working perfectly fine. Could you be so kind and provide me with the snippet of code you implemented to get this solution working.

Comment: from line `var comboFilters = comboFilter.split(', ');` to end of the function

Comment: On the fiddle, I cannot unselect "All Types" and "All Brands" after they have been automatically unselected and I reselected them.